# Powershell - Insert node between two others

Tags: powershell

I would like to insert a node between 2 others already existing.
In my script, I receive a xml variable and I would like to update this one.

Ex :

```
<mapping ...>
    <INSTANCE .. />
    <INSTANCE .. />
    <CONNECTOR .. />
    <CONNECTOR .. />
</mapping>
```

*the result should be :*

```
<mapping ...>
    <INSTANCE .. />
    <INSTANCE .. />
    <NEWINSERT .../>
    <CONNECTOR .. />
    <CONNECTOR .. />
</mapping>
```

When I use a appendChild, the insert is done always done at the end...

An idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 12):

As @Grhm answered, you can do it by `InsertAfter`. I would recommend always to try to pipe it to `Get-Member` to get the hint.

```
> $x = [xml]@"
<mapping>
    <INSTANCE a="abc" />
    <INSTANCE a="abc" />
    <CONNECTOR a="abc" />
    <CONNECTOR a="abc" />
</mapping>
"@

> $x | gm -membertype method

   TypeName: System.Xml.XmlDocument
Name                        MemberType Definition
----                        ---------- ----------
AppendChild                 Method     System.Xml.XmlNode AppendChild(System.Xml
..
ImportNode                  Method     System.Xml.XmlNode ImportNode(System.Xml.
InsertAfter                 Method     System.Xml.XmlNode InsertAfter(System.Xml
InsertBefore                Method     System.Xml.XmlNode InsertBefore(System.Xm
Load                        Method     System.Void Load(string filename), System
...
WriteTo                     Method     System.Void WriteTo(System.Xml.XmlWriter

> $newe = $x.CreateElement('newelement')
> $x.mapping.InsertAfter($newe, $x.mapping.INSTANCE[1])
> $x | Format-Custom
```

Personally I think `gm` (or `Get-Member`) is the most useful cmdlet in PowerShell ;)

Comment: Yep, my big four cmdlets are: Get-Help, Get-Command, Get-Member and Get-PSDrive.  The four keys to the PowerShell kingdom.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest that using `appendChild` is your problem - it appends the node to the end of the list.

Prehaps you could use `InsertBefore` or `InsertAfter` instead (assuming you can get a reference to a node either side of the desired insertion point.

See MSDN for docs on [InsertAfter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertafter.aspx) or [InsertBefore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertbefore.aspx).